# Controlling Element Height With jQuery - Why Isn't This Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the height of a div element with a function triggered by "onmouseover" in jQuery. However, when I hover over the element, nothing happens. There are no errors in the console and as far as I can see this should be working. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks for your help.

```js
function lowerRaise() {
  var getHeiggt = document.getElementsByClassName('searchItem')[0];
  var tehHeiegt = jQuery(getHeiggt).height();
  var allTIms = document.getElementsByClassName('searchItem');
  
  if (tehHeiegt > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < allTIms.length; i++) {
      jQuery(allTIms[i]).height("9px");
      jQuery(allTIms[i]).css("padding-top", "3px");
      jQuery(allTIms[i]).css("padding-bottom", "10px");
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < allTIms.length; i++) {
      jQuery(allTIms[i]).height("0px");
      jQuery(allTIms[i]).css("padding-top", "0px");
      jQuery(allTIms[i]).css("padding-bottom", "0px");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.searchItem {
  height: 9px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px 0px 10px 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchItem a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.searchItem a:hover {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.searchItem:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onmouseover="lowerRaise()" role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/">
  <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s">
     </label>
  <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="searchDrop" style="transition: 0.5s;">
  <div class="searchItem"><a style="" href="/?s=dress">Dresses</a></div>
  <div class="searchItem">Sweaters</div>
  <div class="searchItem">Blouses</div>
  <div class="searchItem">Pants</div>
  <div class="searchItem">Tops</div>
  <div class="searchItem">T-Shirts</div>
  <div class="searchItem">Skirts</div>
  <div class="searchItem">Shirts</div>
  <div class="searchItem">Blazers</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code "works", the issue is that when the first for loop runs, those three commands change the height and css props to the exact values the elements already have. (plus, if your goal is to create an auto-complete search field, there are other ways to do that)

Comment: If you are trying to create your own custom drop down, I advice against doing so.  It's actually a ton of work to get right.  [5 Common Usability Pitfalls of Custom Designed Drop-Downs](https://baymard.com/blog/custom-dropdowns-cause-issues)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for pointing out my mistake - I guess that is what happens at the end of the long day!! Also, no Im not trying to recreate an autocomplete search field, a client specifically wanted these selections to show up beneath the search bar in this way!